# How to grep only ports from nmap scan output file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, nmap

```
➜ cat nmap/ports.nmap
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-21 11:30 IST
Warning: 10.10.10.100 giving up on port because retransmission cap hit (10).
Nmap scan report for 10.10.10.100
Host is up (0.26s latency).
Not shown: 65410 closed tcp ports (reset), 111 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT      STATE SERVICE
88/tcp    open  kerberos-sec
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
389/tcp   open  ldap
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
464/tcp   open  kpasswd5
593/tcp   open  http-rpc-epmap
636/tcp   open  ldapssl
49152/tcp open  unknown
49153/tcp open  unknown
49154/tcp open  unknown
49155/tcp open  unknown
49157/tcp open  unknown
49158/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 17.57 seconds
```

After searching, I use this command.

```
cat nmap/ports.nmap | grep 'open' | awk '{ print $1 }' | awk '{print ($0+0)}' | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/'
```

Output:

```
88,135,139,389,445,464,593,636,49152,49153,49154,49155,49157,49158
```

Is there any simpler command than this, can anyone please help me.

Comment: You can use `nmap --open ....` to show *only* the open ports. So you won't have to use `grep open`

Answer (score 1):

I would probably work with the XML output from `nmap`, which makes it easier to extract the wanted information.

Here I'm getting the port number for each open port in the result of the scan using `xmlstarlet`, and then I'm using `paste` to format the lines of port numbers onto a single line with comma-delimited fields:

```bash
$ nmap -oX - localhost | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//port[state/@state="open"]/@portid' -nl | paste -s -d, -
22,25,111,2049,7000,7001
```

You may do that in two steps if you want to save the result first:

```bash
$ nmap -oX nmap.xml localhost
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-21 08:53 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000057s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 994 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
2049/tcp open  nfs
7000/tcp open  afs3-fileserver
7001/tcp open  afs3-callback

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.13 seconds
```

```bash
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//port[state/@state="open"]/@portid' -nl nmap.xml | paste -s -d, -
22,25,111,2049,7000,7001
```

The XPath query `//port[state/@state="open"]/@portid` locates any `port` node in the XML document that has a `state` child node with a `state` attribute with value `open`.  For each such `port` node, the `portid` attribute is extracted.

---

If you just want to have a variation of what you already have, you may combine most of the parsing in a single `awk` call:

```bash
awk '$2 == "open" { sub("/.*","",$1); print $1 }' nmap.out | paste -s -d, -
```

This detects the word `open` in the second field and extracts and prints everything before the `/` in the first field.  The comma-delimited list is created with `paste` as before.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat nmap/ports.nmap | awk -F/ '/open/ {b=b","$1} END {print substr(b,2)}'
```

Just use awk?

> 88,135,139,389,445,464,593,636,49152,49153,49154,49155,49157,49158

Answer (score 0):

Original command:

```
cat nmap/ports.nmap | grep 'open' | awk '{ print $1 }' | awk '{print ($0+0)}' | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/'
```

Sort and delete duplicate ports command:

```
cat nmap/ports.nmap | grep 'open' | awk '{ print $1 }' | awk '{print ($0+0)}' | sort | uniq | sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).